# Rails - Let users sign in from multiple devices without destroying session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, ruby-on-rails-4

In my rails app currently, I store sessions & cookies so user's are automatically logged back in when they revisit the site. Right now, if a user logs into the site on a different device, say their tablet, the original device's session is destroyed and that user will have to re-login when going back to that device. 

What I want is to allow a user to log in on their phone, tablet, and computer without having to re-login on each device. I hope this is making sense...

Here are some of the sessions method in my user model

```
def User.new_remember_token
  SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
end

def User.encrypt(token)
  Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(token.to_s)
end
```

And here is the create action for my SessionsController

```
user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
  sign_in user
  ...
else
  ...
end
```

Thanks for taking a look at it.

Comment: Not nearly enough information here to help.  What authentication system are you using? Devise? Authlogic? etc...

Answer (score 3):

This only makes sense to me if you use a server-side session store. If you use Rails' default CookieStore, the sign in is bound to and unique for each device. Logging in or out on a tablet cannot affect, say, a separate session running in parallel on a desktop.